# How do I calculate the px value for a media query of a special phone?

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-devices

How is the px value for media-query calculated?

For example: iPhone 7, 8 and X = 375px media-query

iPhone X has the following specs:

- 1.125 x 2.436 Pixel
  -5.8 inches
  -463 dpi

So why is the media query on 375px. How to calculate?

I ask because there are some android phones with crazy specs, and our "normal" query does not work.

Comment: 1px = 1/96th of 1inch. So, iPhone X uses 463 dots (hardware dots) to show 96 pixels. This looks crispier, sharper, more HD etc. than a device that uses only 240 or 300 dots for the same 96 pixels (or 1inch of display area). The crux is that you still have 96 pixels covering 1 inch of the devices display, whatever the DPI. My advice: ignore the DPI and focus on the devices viewport width/height in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

There's a parameter usually called *pixel density* or *device pixel ratio (DPR)*. The browser on a phone, table or desktop will scale the px value to the actual number of pixels on the screen. For example an iPhone 6/7/8 have a pixel density of 3.

So if you take 1125 / 3 = 375.

If you look at the [CSS documentation about units](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp) you can see that the `px` unit is actually a relative unit to the viewport, which can cause confusion, but was necessary in the world of high DPI screens without rewriting every site.

Comment: You read the W3Schools doc wrong. '* Pixels (px) are relative to the viewing device'.  Pixel values themselves are always and have always been fixed values. Hence the line 'pixels (1px = 1/96th of 1in) '. The DPI multiplication factor is what makes them 'seem' relative.

Comment: @RenevanderLende In practical terms is relative as the user can change the pixel density on the device, and thus the viewport. I don't even know what exact DPI I have on my laptop. I've set it to be 1.4x the native resolution (full HD) on a 13.3" screen. So it's probably 107px/inch rather than 96px/inch. (but I've amended my answer to say it's relative to the viewport)